# mdadm array, Error mounting system-managed device /dev/md0: can't read superblock on /dev/md0

Tags: mdadm

Hi I'm having trouble with my 16Tb (5x4tb) mdadm array. It works fine untill i get a power cut or turn off the machine forcefully, and then upon restart and i try to access it i get the error message "Unable to access location - Error mounting system-managed device /dev/md0: can't read superblock on /dev/md0"

What's most frustrating is got it to work again a good 6 months ago but i'm and idiot and didn't write down what i did. So i know its possible and i shouldn't have to loose any data, and i remember it being rather simple but i cant remember what i did.

I ran mdadm --detail and this is what i got

```
/dev/md0:        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Jun  6 17:31:25 2018
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 15627548672 (14903.59 GiB 16002.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906887168 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Tue Apr  2 16:06:18 2019
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : NAS:0  (local to host NAS)
           UUID : ba6b1fc2:13f583af:fa9b2c4b:007a08fb
         Events : 5257

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
       1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
       2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
       3       8       64        3      active sync   /dev/sde        5       8       80        4      active sync   /dev/sdf
```

So all the disks seem to be ok and i remember it being 1 or 2 simple commands, are there any other things you need to know to help me? please let me know and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so i found a soloution, as i said, simple, 2 lines of code, it was a problem with the a superblock.

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/md0
sudo mount /dev/md0
```

All working again, and ive written the answer down on libre, by pen and printed it off and answered on here. 
Should remember/know what to do in the next 6 months :P

Comment: Thank you this was spot on! 
As a pro tip the fsck command may ask to say "yes" a LOT, if instead of 'y' you press 'a' (for all) it just assumes yes for all queries and goes through it very fast!